# Nginx Rewrite router

Tags: nginx, mod-rewrite

Bom dia galera,

existe alguma forma que eu possa fazer as regras abaixo sem ter que ficar sempre repetindo a pasta raiz, nesse caso sem precisar de toda ver escrever "*rewrite ^/pw/... /pw/... last;*"

```
location /pw {
    rewrite ^/pw/styles/min/img/((.)*) /pw/assets/frontend/img/$1 last;
    rewrite ^/pw/styles/min/fontes/((.)*) /pw/assets/frontend/fontes/$1 last;

    rewrite ^/pw/([^/]*)/css/img/((.)*) /pw/assets/$1/img/$2 last;
    rewrite ^/pw/([^/]*)/css/((.)*) /pw/assets/$1/css/$2 last;
    rewrite ^/pw/([^/]*)/js/((.)*) /pw/assets/$1/js/$2 last;
    rewrite ^/pw/([^/]*)/plugins/((.)*) /pw/assets/$1/plugins/$2 last;
    rewrite ^/pw/([^/]*)/fonts/((.)*) /pw/assets/$1/fonts/$2 last;
    rewrite ^/pw/([^/]*)/img/((.)*) /pw/assets/$1/img/$2 last;

    try_files $uri $uri/ /pw/index.php?$args;
}
```